# Reflect-metadata suddenly breaking in Sharepoint Framework

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, webpack, decorator

I wrote an NPM module for use in my SharePoint Framework webpart that uses `reflect-metadata`

```
import "reflect-metadata";

export function someDecorator(name: string): ClassDecorator {
    return target => {
        Reflect.defineMetadata("MyDecorator", name, target);
    }
}
```

This was using fine for a few months until yesterday my spfx app suddenly started failing with:

```
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file 'Reflect.ts': Error: Can't resolve './Reflect.ts' in '/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/reflect-metadata'
    at emitWarning (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:117:16)
    at /mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js:64:7
    at onError (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:65:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/mnt/tmp/my-webpart/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
```

That's from building the exact same code that was just working fine two days ago.

So what could cause this? Why is it suddenly looking for a non-existent `Reflect.ts` file? And, most importantly, how can I get it working again?

Answer (score 1):

If you manually add [Reflect.ts](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata/blob/master/Reflect.ts) to `/node_modules/reflect-metadata` your build should succeed.

See [issue#95](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata/issues/95) and [pr#89](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata/pull/89)

I opted to copy Reflect.ts into my source code and import this local file instead of `"reflect-metadata"`.

Note with this solution:

1. tslint warnings occurred so I added `/* tslint:disable */` to the top of the file.
2. ts error is in file "Type 'symbol' cannot be used as an index type." due to the TS version spfx uses vs the version reflect-metadata uses. I replaced `map[key]` with `map[key as string | number]` to get rid of error.

Alternatively, you could fork reflect-metadata and release an updated npm module that includes Reflect.ts.